# TypeError: bot.guilds.foreach is not a function Discord.JS

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I'm trying to code my bot a function so then when I restart it, the bot leaves every single guild it is in. I make it so that it has to go through a setTimeout function first because I want to get the warning out by displaying it through the bot's status. But when it does get to finish delaying the code, the following error occurs in the Console : `TypeError: bot.guilds.foreach is not a function`

I've went to Reddit to get some code for the file, but none of them seem to work and I've also tried just removing the (function) from the code where it wants to leave all the servers.

(This is a portion of the code)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = bot => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online`)
    bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'Ready!' }, status: `online` });

    /*let statuses = [
        `${bot.guilds.size} guilds!`,
        `${bot.users.size} users!`,
        `${bot.channels.size} channels!`
    ]
    setInterval(function() {
      let status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)];
      bot.user.setActivity(status, {type: "WATCHING"});
      bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `Loading...` }, status: `dnd` }); 

    }, 1000) */
    setTimeout(function(){
      bot.guilds.foreach( guildFound => { guildFound.leave(); });
   }, 12000);

   setTimeout(function(){
    bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `Leaving all servers...` }, status: `idle` });
 }, 10);

   setTimeout(function(){
  bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `Leaving in 3s.` }, status: `online` });
}, 7000);

setTimeout(function(){
  bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `Leaving in 2s.` }, status: `idle` });
}, 8000);

setTimeout(function(){
  bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `Leaving in 1s.` }, status: `idle` });
}, 9000);

setTimeout(function(){
  bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `placeholder` }, status: `dnd` });
}, 10000);
```

Expected: After about 12000 ms, or 12 seconds, all warning messages are sent through the bot's status and the bot leaves every single guild that the bot is joined to.

Error: When running through VSC, I get an error : `TypeError: bot.guilds.foreach is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `bots.guilds.forEach(` with an Capital E.